# parsley.js form validation - confirm when no errors found on form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, parsley.js

I have read the parsley.js docs but I am still learning JQuery so it goes in one ear and out the other.

I think I need to add a custom event listener to achieve what I need, but I am really not sure, so some help would be appreciated.

I have a form with parsley.js embedded. The form works as expected but I have to add some functionality to the form.

**How would I display an alert message (alert('no client side errors!');) to the user when all the client side errors have been cleared or when there are no client side errors when the form is submitted?**

Here is an example of my form code:

```
<form id="name_details_form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" data-parsley-validate>

    <div id="row_id_name_details_first_name" class="control-group">
        <label for="id_name_details_first_name" class="control-label required">First Names:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-maxlength="200" data-parsley-required-message="This field is required." maxlength="200" type="text" id="id_name_details_first_name" name="name_details_first_name" class="input-xxlarge parsley-error" data-parsley-id="8581" dir="ltr"><span class="parsley-errors-list filled" id="parsley-id-8581" style="display: none;"><span class="parsley-required">This field is required.</span></span>  
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="row_id_name_details_middle_name" class="control-group">
        <label for="id_name_details_middle_name" class="control-label ">Middle Names:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input id="id_name_details_middle_name" type="text" name="name_details_middle_name" data-parsley-maxlength="200" maxlength="200" class="input-xlarge" data-parsley-id="7500"><span class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-7500" style="display: none;"></span> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="row_id_name_details_last_name" class="control-group  ">
        <label for="id_name_details_last_name" class="control-label required">Last Names:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-maxlength="200" data-parsley-required-message="This field is required." maxlength="200" type="text" id="id_name_details_last_name" name="name_details_last_name" class="input-xxlarge parsley-success" data-parsley-id="7577" dir="ltr"><span class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-7577" style="display: none;"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr />

    <input class="btn-u btn-u-blue" type="submit" value="Add">

</form>

<script>
    ....
</script>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This code shows the alert message when the form is submitted and the all fields are valid.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // bind parsley to the form
        $("#name_details_form").parsley();

        // on form submit
        $("#name_details_form").on('submit', function(event) {
            // validate form with parsley.
            $(this).parsley().validate();

            // if this form is valid
            if ($(this).parsley().isValid()) {
                // show alert message
                alert('no client side errors!');
            }

            // prevent default so the form doesn't submit. We can return true and
            // the form will be submited or proceed with a ajax request.
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. That code works great. I would not have got that to work by myself.

Comment: This will work but didn't show an error message if we applied on another button.

Comment: @ankitsuthar what do you mean by "applied on another button"? If you have another button that doesn't submit the form, you should update the binding using `$(yourbutton).on('click', function() { ...`

Comment: is there any way to make it works with keyup?

 $('form').on('keyup', function() {
      if ($('form').parsley().isValid()) {
         $('#submit').prop('disabled', false).addClass('valid');
      } else {
         $('#submit').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      }
   });